# How to translate USER_OBJECTS.TEMPORARY in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have this code in Oracle:

```
SELECT *
FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE  TEMPORARY = 'N'
```

I know that the USER_OBJECT table in Postgres is pg_catalog.pg_class, but what's the equivalent of the TEMPORARY column?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_class 
WHERE relpersistence = 't';
```

REF: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html

relpersistence char
p = permanent table/sequence, u = unlogged table/sequence, t = temporary table/sequence

Answer (score 0):

That can be found in [relpersistence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html): t = temporary table

```
SELECT relpersistence, * FROM pg_class;
```